# Regex for key-value-pair including unescaped whitespace

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need a regex for parsing key-value-pairs from a properties-file to write them into a database. The application is written in java. As I need to store information about comment-lines and empty lines, properties.load does not work for me

Key is everything until the first appearance of an unescaped whitespace or an equals sign (including escaped whitespaces).
Value is everything until end of line, but can also be empty.

It has to match the following cases:

- key=value
- key value
- key=value value
- key
- key value value
- key\ key\ key=value
- key\ key\ key value

I tried the following regex, but it does not seperate the last two cases correctly:

```
^(\\\s|[^\s=]+)+[\s|=](.*)?$
```

For the last two examples I get on Rubular:

```
1. key\
2. key\ key value
```

instead of

```
1. key\ key\ key
2. value
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313848/regex-to-match-non-whitespace-or-space-prefixed-with), but it does not work for me, too

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\\\\)\s` when checking your space

```
^((.*?)((?<!\\\\)\\s|=)(.*?)|(\\w+))$
```

Breaking it down

```
(.*?)             Match everything non greedy up to the next match
((?<!\\\\)\\s|=)  Match witespace not preceded by \\
(.*?)             Again match everything non greedy up to the next match
|\\w+             Or match strings with no whitespace - this captures case 3 with no value
```

Each case tested with the tool here http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Comment: You could also use `(.*?)(((?<!\\\\)\\s|=)(.*?))?` to consistently use group #1 to get the key and group #4 to get the value. Unless you really need to match the start/end of the string, you could leave those out since `Matcher.matches()` will match the entire string.

Comment: @Dan-Cruz Very nice simplification - you should add it as your own answer and get some credit for it.

Comment: @cordsen Duly noted and thanks for the suggestion. I do feel you deserve the credit for the answer; you posted it before I and all I provided was a small tweak.

Answer (score 0):

try (remember this is plain regex, so you have to beware of backslashes escape when writing it as Java strings):

```
^(\\\s|[^\s=])+(.*)$
```

Comment: This regex only captures the last character of the key.

Comment: @Sebastian: right, sorry I have no tools to test here, just using my brain :)

Comment: @Martijn: nope, as I said, it's a PLAIN regex, not inside Java strings.