# Regex Non Whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add non whitespace to my javascript. I am currently checking for letters only, but now I need to add a non whitespace code to it. This is what I have:

```
var regexNamePattern = /^[a-zA-Z /-]{2,30}$/;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex to match non-whitespace OR space prefixed with '\\'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313848/regex-to-match-non-whitespace-or-space-prefixed-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is `\s` and non-whitespace is `\S`.

```
var regexNamePattern = /^\S{2,30}$/;
```